# Python-pcl rotate coordinate system

Tags: python, point-cloud-library

Is there a way to rotate the coordinate system or the point cloud in python-pcl?
I saw that there is a function in c++ `void pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addCoordinateSystem` that can take a transformation matrix or X position, Y position and Z position of the axes as input. In python-pcl the function `AddCoordinateSystem()` only takes the scale, id and the viewport as input.

Comment: PCLVisualizer::addCoordinateSystem adds 3 bars with color red, green, blue. In CPP, The input can be an Eigen::Affine (or simply a Pose) and the scale (how big this bars should be). Here's example, the left part of the image is the coordinate system http://www.pcl-users.org/file/n4034466/31.png

I would suggest you to use the CPP version of PCL. `It has pcl::transformPointCloud` that might help you with transformation of point cloud.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C++ so I would like to stay with python. Isn't there any function like `pcl::transformPointCloud` in python-pcl? Maybe I can use another library just to transform the cloud.